# How to loop a link using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hey so I have this line of code. It should visit google and refresh the page 15 times. Then close the driver and open it again another 15 times and then close the browser again and so on. It should keep doing that until the program is stopped.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
count = 15

while count != 0:
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    count -= 1
driver.close()
```

This is my code so far. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

To visit the url `https://www.google.com/` and refresh the page 15 times. Then close the driver and open it again another 15 times and then close the browser again and so on you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  while True:
      try:
          driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
          for _ in range(15):
              driver.refresh()
              print("Page Refreshed")
          driver.quit()
      except:
          break
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50307/devtools/browser/d97baf5f-2088-4acf-8f1a-a6568d82c649
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  [8700:3392:0823/020728.931:ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50348/devtools/browser/9113e8a1-d82b-4a87-95c9-5e82917ceeb0
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed
  Page Refreshed

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50388/devtools/browser/2ce95680-edbc-4391-b516-0fb0ab136c54
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `driver.get('https://google.com/')` to refresh the page, try using `driver.refresh()`. At the same time, instead of using a while loop, you should try to use a for loop. Here's how I would do it

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for iters in range(15):
    driver.refresh()
driver.close()
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: That's helpful if I wanted to refresh but I don't I'm working on a project for work and cant share the code. But it's really similar to this except its to visit another webpage. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Oh. I thought you had to refresh the page! No worries. Just change the while loop to a for loop. Beyond that, you did it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You are not far from what you want to achieve, the on challenge is the terminal condition of you `while` loop, by writing `while count != 0`, you are asking your loop to run for all values of `count` from 15 to negative infinity but to skip 0. This should make you program run infinitely.
You can better get it done this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
count = 15
while count > 0:
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    count -= 1
driver.close()
```

so your loop terminates once `count` becomes less than 1

Comment: But I want to loop multiple times. Won't this code just end after refreshing 15 times? I would like the code to restart the web driver after every 15 refreshes